# MySQL sum, count with group by and joins

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have three tables types, post and insights.

- Types table contains the types of post.
- post table contains the post that have been made.
- the insight table contains the insights of post on daily basis.

Here is the link to my sql fiddle [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89688/3).

Now i want to generate a report which contains number of post against each type and the sum of their likes and comments i.e. Type | COUNT(post_id) | SUM(likes) | SUM(comments).

These are my tries:

```
select type_name, count(p.post_id), sum(likes), sum(comments)
from types t
left join posts p on t.type_id = p.post_type
left join insights i on p.post_id = i.post_id
group by type_name;
```

**Result**: Aggregate values are not correct.

```
select type_name, count(p.post_id), p.post_id, 
  (select sum(likes) from insights where post_id = p.post_id) as likes, 
  (select sum(comments)from insights where post_id = p.post_id) as comments
from types t
left join posts p on t.type_id = p.post_type
group by type_name;
```

**Result**: Displays the sum of likes and comments of only one post.

Comment: Using an `inner join` with distinct `count` is not an option? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89688/17

Comment: Aggregate values are not correct. The sum of likes and comments are 63 and 28 for link type post.

Comment: Hmm. I counted them and I think they are correct!?

Comment: Yeah that was my mistake i was confused between type id and post id and counting the wrong rows. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt was real close. But each `post_id` was being multiplied by the number of matches in `insights`, so you need to use `DISTINCT`:

```
select type_name, count(distinct p.post_id), sum(likes), sum(comments)
from types t
left join posts p on t.type_id = p.post_type
left join insights i on p.post_id = i.post_id
group by type_name;
```

Alternatively, you can group with a subquery that combines all the insights for the same post:

```
select type_name, count(*), sum(likes), sum(comments)
from types t
left join posts p on t.type_id = p.post_type
left join (select post_id, sum(likes) likes, sum(comments) comments
           from insights
           group by post_id) i on p.post_id = i.post_id
group by type_name;
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89688/24)

Comment: Aggregate values are not correct. The sum of likes and comments are 63 and 28 for link type post.

Comment: first one looks better, I wouldn't do the second unless thre is something I'm missing

Comment: @ShayanHusaini when I run your first listed attempt I get 51 and 24, which looks right, yes?

Comment: Oops my mistake i was confused between the type id and post id thats why my calculations were wrong.

Comment: The first one is probably best for this particular case. I showed the second one because this idiom can be useful in more complex cases.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT types.type_name, stats.posts, stats.likes, stats.comments
FROM types
LEFT JOIN (
select post_type, count(i.post_id) as posts, sum(i.likes) as likes, sum(i.comments) as comments
from insights i INNER JOIN posts p ON i.post_id = p.post_id
) as stats
ON types.type_id = stats.post_type;
```

Comment: I think you are missing a GROUP BY post_type in the subquery.

Comment: I tried, and indeed it misses a group by in the subquery. 


`SELECT types.type_name, stats.posts, stats.likes, stats.comments
FROM types
LEFT JOIN (
select post_type, count(i.post_id) as posts, sum(i.likes) as likes, sum(i.comments) as comments
from insights i INNER JOIN posts p ON i.post_id = p.post_id
group by post_type) as stats
ON types.type_id = stats.post_type;`